# Which log4j Version is bundled with latest OpenCms 7?

Tags: java, content-management-system, log4j, opencms

Which log4j Version is bundled with latest OpenCms 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCms 7.5.3 includes log4j **1.2.15**

Answer (score 1):

OpenCms [7.0.5](http://www.opencms.org/en/modules/downloads/dl_7.0.5_dist.html) includes log4j **1.2.14**